# Run multiple javascript code for imacros inside a javascript file (iim, js)

Tags: macros, javascript, imacros

I have Windows 7, Firefox 56, Imacros 8.9.7

I need to run multiple imacros javascript code in sequence one after the other.

With iim imacros extension I can use this command inside the javascript macro starter

Example run_all_macro.js

```
iimPlay("macro1.iim")
iimPlay("macro2.iim")
iimPlay("macro3.iim")
iimPlay("macro4.iim")
```

I need to run macro in javascript format and this code do not works

Example run_all_macro.js

```
iimPlay("macro1.js")
iimPlay("macro2.js")
iimPlay("macro3.js")
iimPlay("macro4.js")
```

Example of macro1.js

```
var imacros = "PROXY ADDRESS=12.3.4.5:67" + "\n";
imacros += "URL GOTO=javascript:{document.getElemensByClassName('class_here')[0].click();undefined;}" + "\n";
iimPlayCode(imacros);
```

How can i run multiple javascript code inside a javascript code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create JS-function which reads you js-files and run them.

```
//set Datasource folder to JS variable
iimPlayCode("SET !EXTRACT {{!FOLDER_DATASOURCE}}");
let folderDatasource = iimGetLastExtract();

//Read JS-file and run it
function readImacrosFileAndRun(filename){
    let file_i = imns.FIO.openNode(folderDatasource+"/"+filename);
    let fileCode = imns.FIO.readTextFile(file_i);
    eval(fileCode);
}


readImacrosFileAndRun("macro1.js")
readImacrosFileAndRun("macro2.js")
readImacrosFileAndRun("macro3.js")
readImacrosFileAndRun("macro4.js")
```